# VBA Change error handling method during code execution

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro, and part of the code is concerned with:
1) detecting if a column contains empty cells - if so filling them with some value
2) detecting if a column contains cells containing errors (such as N/A) and if so filling them with some value

Now if there are no error/empty cells in the column, the line that finds them gives a "Run-time error 1004 no cells were found".

I use error handling to skip this with GoTo.

Below is the code - the first error handling GoTo works perfectly, while the second gives the expected error, although there is Error handling GoTo set, that does not seem to work. Code with comments:

```
On Error GoTo EErrorOne


'depending on file I get, below line will generate error and code successfully skips to ErrorOne label

Workbooks(nazwawb).Sheets(szitnr).Columns(ktorepole).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeBlanks)

' code to be skipped

    Workbooks(nazwawb).Sheets(szitnr).Columns(ktorepole).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Value = "Some Value"

' end of code to be skipped

EErrorOne:

' successfully skipped error line by now. Below line should set a new Error handling procedure.

On Error GoTo EErrorTwo



Workbooks(nazwawb).Sheets(szitnr).Columns(ktorepole).Select

' Below line generates an error but does not skip to EErrorTwo label as detailed in the current Error handling procedure

Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).Select   

' code to be skipped


Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).Select
    Selection.Value = "Some Value"

' end of code to be skipped


EErrorTwo:



' Below line should reset error handling procedure to normal for subsequent handling of other errors:
On Error GoTo 0
```

It seems that error handling procedure (GoTo specific label) is ignored, and instead, an error message is shown as if the error handling was reset to GoTo 0. How do I skip the second error?

Comment: It would be better to create code that doesnt rely on error handlers to function. Do a check for the condition causing the error instead and skip over the code that you know is going to cause an error.

Comment: braX, I tried assigning concerned cells to a range and then setting if not rangename is nothing, but it still evaluated to an error message. Mat's Mug, I am not an expert in this, though I suspected that I need to quit error handling before starting anew, but I thought that On Error GoTo 0 would reset error handling - and it turns out it should've been On Error GoTo -1, as pointed out in the accepted answer to my question. Anyways I did not reset error handling where I should have, which is the solution to my problem. Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside error handling routines, it seems as though defining new error handling routines won't work, unless you clear the previously set error routine (https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/):

```
'...
EErrorOne:
On Error GoTo -1 'Clears error trap flag
On Error GoTo EErrorTwo 'Reset error handling
'...
```

---

**Edit after accepted:**
As was discussed in the comments, `On Error GoTo -1` clears the error trap flag, while `Err.Clear` only clears the error.
The code below illustrates this by creating two errors and trying to trap them.

`On Error Goto -1` allows the second error to be trapped by the `On Error GoTo NextLabel` line and the code jumps to the label when the error occurs.
`Err.Clear` keeps the first error live, so when the second error occurs the error message is displayed rather than the code jumping to the label.

```
Sub ClearErr()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Worksheet

    'Jump to label when "Division by 0" occurs.
    On Error GoTo ErrorLabel

    x = 1 / 0
    Debug.Print x

ErrorLabel:

    'On Error GoTo -1 'Next error is trapped.
    Err.Clear   'Untrapped error on y=Worksheets(1)

    'Jump to label when "Object Variable not set" occurs.
    On Error GoTo NextLabel

    y = Worksheets(1)
    Debug.Print y.Name

NextLabel:

End Sub
```

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook `Err.Clear`clears error, but doesn't clear error trap flag! Make a try.

Comment: It doesn't?  I'll have to look at that.  I'd still recommend jumping out of the main procedure to deal with any errors and using `RESUME`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Try.

Comment: Fair enough - tried.  Is it ok if I update your answer with the code that demonstrates it?

Answer (score 7):

You're not clearing your errors when they occur, just trying to jump over them and the code is wondering what's going on with the error.

As Chip Pearson says on his site:

> When the first error is raised, execution transfers to the line
>   following Err1:. The error hander is still active when the second
>   error occurs, and therefore the second error is not trapped by the On
>   Error statement

and continues with

> The Resume statement instructs VBA to resume execution at a specified
>   point in the code.  You can use  Resume only in an error handling
>   block; any other use will cause an error. Moreover, Resume is the only
>   way, aside from exiting the procedure, to get out of an error handling
>   block. Do not use the Goto statement to direct code execution out of
>   an error handling block.  Doing so will cause strange problems with
>   the error handlers.
>   http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

The ideal way is to avoid the error in the first place - check the workbook exists before opening it, check the sheet exists in the workbook before trying to reference it and if an error occurs jump out of the main body of the routine, deal with the error and then jump back in again.

As an example:

```
Sub Test()

    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

    '.... code ....

FAST_EXIT:
    'Code to tidy up, clear references etc before finishing.

Exit Sub

ERR_HANDLE:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 1004
            'Code to resolve error
            '.
            '.
            'Resume - clear error, jump back to line that caused it.
            'Resume Next - clear error, jump to line after the one that caused error.
            'Resume FAST_EXIT - clear error and go to line label.

        Case 92 'Do something else to resolve error.

        Case Else
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: To further clarify on Darren's answer, an error handler is active until the code is explicitly told otherwise. Standard error handling uses an `On Error GoTo SomeLineLabel : Error Handling Code After Label : Resume or Resume Next`. The final statement is what, in essence, clears the error.

Comment: What @Brandon said.  Was trying to get that across with _clear error, jump back to line that caused it._.  Needed to be more explicit that _clear error_ was important in each case.