# VBA Error Handler - On Error GoTo 0 required before exit sub?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below and I am wondering if "On Error GoTo 0" is required if it's just going to exit sub.
Can I omit that line?

Sorry for the newbie question and thank you in advance.

```
Sub LookForNAs

'some var declarations
'some lengthy code

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
        pt_nca.PivotFields("Group").CurrentPage = "#N/A"
    On Error GoTo 0

'some other lengthy code

ErrorHandler:

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "No #N/As found in the pivot table."
    End If

    Call TurnOnStuff
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes you can. It turns of the error handler which you might or might not want.

Comment: You can omit it, as you soon as you exit the sub the default behaviour for the next routine will be `On Error Goto 0` unless specified otherwise

Comment: Your error handler is incorrect. You don't exit the routine from within the error handler but resume to the actual  *exit* label.

Comment: Thanks guys! @KostasK. I really would like to simply Exit Sub because there is no #NA found and there is no point in continuing the rest of the code. Unless I missed a point of yours that is critical. TurnOnStuff is to turn on DisplayAlerts, EnableEvents, ScreenUpdating, and Calculation.

Comment: How do you exit if there's no error?

Comment: I continue with the code like (copying and pasting) then exit sub, I edited my code above. Sorry, I am a little confused with your question.

Comment: So you're repeating yourself since you still have to call `TurnOnStuff`` in two places. See an example of an error handler here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322130/ma-access-sendobject-on-error-go-back-to-form/62340126#62340126

Comment: Because I need to exit sub immediately that is why I have to Call TurnOnStuff also in the error handler block. Does that make sense?

Comment: As @KostasK. said - you're error handler is incorrect.  Have a read of my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461112/vba-change-error-handling-method-during-code-execution/45461488#45461488) - I'd argue with the accepted answer on there.

Answer (score 1):

I would write your code as below.  I also use variations on the answer given by @Freeflow - useful when checking if a sheet exists and creating it if it doesn't. It would take a lot of work to handle every possible error like that though - especially the errors you're not expecting.

```
Sub LookForNAs()

'some var declarations

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'some lengthy code

    pt_nca.PivotFields("Group").CurrentPage = "#N/A"

'some other lengthy code

Fast_Exit:
    TurnOnStuff
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 1004
            MsgBox "No #N/As found in the pivot table.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, Err.Number
            Resume Fast_Exit
        Case 6
            MsgBox "Overflow error.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, Err.Number
            Resume Fast_Exit
        Case Else 'Catch any unhandled errors.
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, Err.Number
            Resume Fast_Exit
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: That `Resume` could probably go after the `End Select` as it's called each time anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to encapsulate you test for an error into a function which helps you separate the 'happy path' form the 'error path'

```
Public Sub CallerForLookForNAs()

    If TryLookForNAs Then Exit Sub
    'etc 

End Sub

Public Function TryLookForNAs() As Boolean

    TryLookForNAs = False
    On Error Resume Next
    pt_nca.PivotFields("Group").CurrentPage = "#N/A"
    TryLookForNAs = Err.Number > 0
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

This general approach is discussed in more detail in a =Rubberduck blog https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/05/

Comment: Thanks freeflow. I will go back to this page and study everything as I have not grasped the idea yet.

Answer (score 0):

So I omitted the On Error Goto 0, is the below somehow acceptable or not incorrect?

```
Sub LookForNAs()

'some code

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
     pt_nca.PivotFields("Group").CurrentPage = "#N/A"
On Error GoTo 0

' some other code

ErrorHandler:

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "No #N/As found in the pivot table."
        Call TurnOnStuff
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'placeholders for other err.numbers
    'If Err.Number = blah blah blah

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

The object Err contains the number of the error. The problem is that if you omit the line in question when the error arise the execution will block. So that line tells VBA to go to your named block if there is an error. If you omit, it will work but when the error rise the program will stop. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Hi Luigi, will it be a big deal if I am just going to exit sub? Also, I edited my code above just to give you a clearer picture. I have an On Error GoTo 0 outside the label.

Comment: It should work in the way it is now. Does it not? Basically the error handling allows you to capture the error when it is raised. What is the problem now?

Comment: Well my original question is if I can just omit the On Error GoTo 0 in the error handler block since I am just going to exit sub immediately anyway.